# React Tooltip - as we scroll to page, tool tip position gets same , it wont come along with text link

Tags: reactjs, react-tooltip

React Tooltip issue

- React Tooltip is perfectly showing tooltip at bottom position
  applied. But as we scroll little bit webpage , and hover on same link
  again. tooltip goes beyond visible area, it dose not move with text
  that we are hovering..

```
div data-tip data-for={formattedTooltipId} className="form_body">
   <div className="form_rows">
      <div className="form__row" style={{ marginTop: "-2%" }}>
      <Tooltip
         tooltipId={formattedTooltipId}
         value={fieldName.accountName}
         />
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Tooltip - on hover coming, but when screen gets scrolled it wont appear at same position]

Comment: add your code and images how you are doing this and what you are getting

Comment: Can you please edit your title and post, and add images and/or code that explain this issue you're facing?

Answer (score -1):

We tried many css playing for same and able to make it work by adding "overflow: visible" for tbody tag of table and it worked.. :)
It was not problem of actually React tooltip but it was how it was getting away after hover on table td tag...

Thank you :)