# React tooltip, dont show beside the element

Tags: reactjs, react-tooltip

It works fine with other buttons and elements I use on the page, but with the `aside` section that is on a fixed position. The tooltip shows up on the bottom. The next tooltip, for eksample for GitHub, shows up even further down.

I think it has something to do with the position in the CSS code, but I cannot figure it out. Is there anyone that has had the same issue and can help?

CSS:

```css
aside {
  background-color: #16123f;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px #00000045);
}
```

Code from the React component:

```
<aside>
  <ul className="social">
    <li>
      <a data-tip data-for="ePost" href="mailto:stig.ark@gmail.com">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAt} className="fa-solid fa-at fa-lg" />
      </a>
      <ReactTooltip
        backgroundColor="#ed0b70"
        textColor="black"
        id="ePost"
        place="top"
        effect="solid"
      >
        Send meg en epost!
      </ReactTooltip>
    </li>

    // ...
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Here is how it looks, I want it right beside the `aside`.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979474/react-tooltip-as-we-scroll-to-page-tool-tip-position-gets-same-it-wont-come

Comment: I checked the post out. But it did not explain much towards my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to make it look like what you want with the following workaround (note `overridePosition`):

```
<aside>
  <ul className="social">
    <li>
      <a data-tip data-for="ePost" href="mailto:stig.ark@gmail.com">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAt} className="fa-solid fa-at fa-lg" />
      </a>
      <ReactTooltip
        backgroundColor="#ed0b70"
        textColor="black"
        id="ePost"
        place="top"
        effect="solid"
        overridePosition = {() => {return { left: 30, top: -40 };}}
      >
        Send meg en epost!
      </ReactTooltip>
    </li>

    // ...
  </ul>
</aside>
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

As for a proper fix, I do think this is a bug in the library. It may be a good idea to open an issue in [its GitHub reposotory](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip) but unfortunately it's not reasonable to expect a fix anytime soon, considering that the library has more than 250 open issues already and the last commit was more than 3 months ago.

Comment: Thank you very much! So the tooltip basically gets affected by the position of the aside element? So overriding it by the same amount the other way, put it in the position it "should be"? :)

Comment: You're welcome! The tooltip is supposed to know where to appear based on the element it is for (the `<a>` in the `<li>` element in this case). But unfortunately, it doesn't know, so you have to tell it explicitly that it should be 40 pixels above the element.